# How to tint an image in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tint

I am trying to create a color overlay on a minecraft ore block, and i thought the easiest way to do this, was to turn the image into grayscale and put a tint on it.

I have looked all over google trying to find a suitable solution, the only time I have gotten it to work, it was with an online image editor, I have tried using matplotlib, PIL and CV2. There is alot of information online, but none of them does it the right way.

Here is what I have done that came the closest to working

```py
def colorMask(im):
    im = im.convert('RGBA')
    pixeldata = list(im.getdata())

    for i, pixel in enumerate(pixeldata):
        if pixel[3] == 255:
            print(pixel)
            pixeldata[i] = (132,23,96,pixel[1])
    im.putdata(pixeldata)
    im.save("Images/new_ore.png")
```

The code above almost get the right result, except it is just an illusion since the color is the same on every pixel, but the amount of opacity if different.